# How can i set LinearLayout into another LinearLayout programatically in android?

Tags: android

I want to set the layout inside another layout programatically in android.

Here, is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_second_overs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Second textview overs-->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_second_balls"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <!--Second textview balls--> //Here i want to put one linear layout.
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: programatically? so use `ViewGroup#addView` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);

LinearLayout child = new LinearLayout(getApplicationcontext());
child  .LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parent.addView(child);
```

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer ,if it satisfied please upvote @ Milan Gajera

Answer (score 0):

You can add Layout inside root Layout using below way.

```
// This is your parent `LinearLayout`
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);

// Create New LinearLayout inside parent layout using below way.
LinearLayout child = new LinearLayout(context);
parent.addView(child);
```

Additional you can set width and height dynamically.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Set orientation to your parent view and check.